# Grails and CXF plugin WSDL first approach example?

Tags: grails, soap, wsdl, cxf

Hi there i have a need to create a soap implementation of a wsdl first
soap service. Is there any howto on how to achieve this inside a
grails project?

I have to create a server implementation of a wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the new cxf 1.x plugin.  Check out the example in the cxf test source:

CustomerServiceWsdlEndpoint.groovy -> https://github.com/thorstadt/grails-cxf/blob/master/grails-app/endpoints/org/grails/cxf/test/CustomerServiceWsdlEndpoint.groovy

CustomerService.wsdl -> https://github.com/thorstadt/grails-cxf/blob/master/src/java/org/grails/cxf/test/soap/CustomerService.wsdl

Let me know if that doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: both those links are broken